# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x186a0

Tags: android, string, android-recyclerview, resources

I usually use this page to fix my problems, and this is my first time asking, so sorry in advance for any mistake I will do, and thank you for the help!

I am using a RecicleView, admob and Lists for first time and the app is crashing, I was all the night looking for the bug but I just cant find it.

My error los is as follows:

```
03-26 08:19:29.303 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
03-26 08:19:29.303 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
03-26 08:19:29.313 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
03-26 08:19:29.313 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
03-26 08:19:29.313 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
03-26 08:19:29.323 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
03-26 08:19:29.333 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
03-26 08:19:29.333 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
03-26 08:19:29.343 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
03-26 08:19:29.343 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/wvc1
03-26 08:19:29.353 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
03-26 08:19:29.353 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
03-26 08:19:29.353 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
03-26 08:19:29.353 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp43
03-26 08:19:29.363 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/sorenson
03-26 08:19:29.383 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
03-26 08:19:29.433 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
03-26 08:19:29.453 3849-4076/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
03-26 08:19:29.533 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/Ads: Starting ad request.
03-26 08:19:29.613 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/BrokersActivity: A3. Add in mBottomBanner
03-26 08:19:29.613 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/BrokersActivity: A4. mBrokersList
03-26 08:19:29.683 3849-3856/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/art: Suspending all threads took: 51.666ms
03-26 08:19:29.693 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/BrokersActivity: A5. Añado todo a la mBrokersList
03-26 08:19:29.783 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/BrokersActivity: A6. setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); 
03-26 08:19:29.783 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/BrokersActivity: A7. SetOnClickListener
03-26 08:19:29.913 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 56.0.2924.87 (code 292408700)
03-26 08:19:29.933 3849-3864/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37551(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 24(893KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 21MB/25MB, paused 3.845ms total 133.666ms
03-26 08:19:29.973 3849-4120/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                             OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                             Build Date: 01/24/15 Sat
                                                                             Local Branch: AF11_RB1_AU15
                                                                             Remote Branch: 
                                                                             Local Patches: 
                                                                             Reconstruct Branch: 
03-26 08:19:30.013 3849-4120/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-26 08:19:30.154 3849-3856/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.094ms
03-26 08:19:30.164 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
03-26 08:19:30.164 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
03-26 08:19:30.204 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
03-26 08:19:30.254 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
03-26 08:19:30.394 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000186a0
03-26 08:19:30.474 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 1665-1671)
03-26 08:19:30.474 3849-4086/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "56.0.2924.87", actual native library version number "56.0.2924.87"
03-26 08:19:30.474 3849-3849/app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial, PID: 3849
                                                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x186a0
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1334)
                                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4921)
                                                                                     at app.synchronice.com.admobtutorial.BrokerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BrokerAdapter.java:55)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Chore
```

And the App have just 1 activity and 2 classes:

> BrokersActivity.java (activity)

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    public class BrokersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private AdView mBottomBanner;
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private FloatingActionButton fab;
        private RecyclerView mBrokersList;
        private String TAG = "BrokersActivity";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_brokers);

            //DEBUG Log.d(TAG,"");
            Log.i(TAG,"A1. setContentView(R.layout.activity_brokers)");
            //Ui
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            mBottomBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.av_bottom_banner);
            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            Log.i(TAG,"A2. mToolbar, mBottomBanner,fab");

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("82E1680616B2F7473A2CF976AF978D28")  //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            mBottomBanner.loadAd(adRequest);
            Log.i(TAG,"A3. Add in mBottomBanner");

            mBrokersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.brokers_list);
            Log.i(TAG,"A4. mBrokersList");

            BrokerAdapter brokersAdapter = new BrokerAdapter(
                    this,
                    Broker.FAKE_DATA_BROKERS,
                    new BrokerAdapter.BrokerItemClick() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBrokerClick(Broker clickedBroker) {
                            // Lógica
                        }
                    });
            mBrokersList.setAdapter(brokersAdapter);
            Log.i(TAG,"A5. Añado todo a la mBrokersList");

            //Setup
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            Log.i(TAG,"A6. setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); ");


            //SetOnClickListener
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
            Log.i(TAG,"A7. SetOnClickListener");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_brokers, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        //Controles de publicidad
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mBottomBanner != null) {
                mBottomBanner.resume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (mBottomBanner != null) {
                mBottomBanner.pause();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mBottomBanner != null) {
                mBottomBanner.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Broker (class)

```
   public class Broker {
        private String mId;
        private String mName;
        private String mDescription;
        private String TAG = "Broker";

        private int mUsersPerMonth;
        @DrawableRes
        private int mFeaturedImageResId;

        public Broker(String name,
                      String description, int usersPerMonth,
                      @DrawableRes int featuredImageResId) {
            this.mId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            this.mName = name;
            this.mDescription = description;
            this.mUsersPerMonth = usersPerMonth;
            this.mFeaturedImageResId = featuredImageResId;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public void setId(String mId) {
            this.mId = mId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public void setName(String mName) {
            this.mName = mName;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return mDescription;
        }

        public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
            this.mDescription = mDescription;
        }

        public int getUsersPerMonth() {
            return mUsersPerMonth;
        }

        public void setUsersPerMonth(int mUsersPerMonth) {
            this.mUsersPerMonth = mUsersPerMonth;
        }

        public int getFeaturedImageResId() {
            return mFeaturedImageResId;
        }

        public void setFeaturedImageResId(int mFeaturedImageResId) {
            this.mFeaturedImageResId = mFeaturedImageResId;
        }
        public static List<Broker> FAKE_DATA_BROKERS = new ArrayList<>();

        static {
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Forex Mother of dragons",
                    "El mejor broker de forex, abre tu cuenta ya",
                    100000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Black Forex",
                    "Comienza con tan solo 50USD",
                    120000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Be Rich Now",
                    "Entrenate y duplica tu inversión",
                    1920000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Forexgump",
                    "Ve de 100USD a 4000USD en dos semanas",
                    900000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Dinero fácil pro",
                    "Olvidate de tu trabajo y abre una cuenta ahora mismo",
                    14000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Money money money!",
                    "Qué esperas?, invierte tu capital!",
                    100000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Invertsor",
                    "Operaciones forex de práctica",
                    40000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Forex Machine",
                    "Entra y descubre una estrategia nunca antes revelada",
                    30000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Forexme",
                    "Explota tu inversión",
                    220000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
            FAKE_DATA_BROKERS.add(new Broker("Aprende algo dinero",
                    "De la mano de los mejores maestros del trading",
                    200000, R.drawable.broker_forex_g));
        }
    }
```

> BrokerAdapter (class)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class BrokerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<Broker> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private BrokerItemClick mItemClickListener;
    private String TAG = "BrokersAdapter";

    public BrokerAdapter(Context context,
                          List<Broker> brokers,
                          BrokerItemClick brokerItemClick) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = brokers;
        mItemClickListener = brokerItemClick;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        switch (viewType) {
            default:
                view = layoutInflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item_broker, parent, false);
                return new BrokerViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Broker currentItem = mItems.get(position);
        BrokerViewHolder brokerViewHolder = (BrokerViewHolder) holder;

        brokerViewHolder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
        brokerViewHolder.description.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
        brokerViewHolder.usersPerMonth.setText(currentItem.getUsersPerMonth()); //formatUsersPerMonth
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(currentItem.getFeaturedImageResId())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(brokerViewHolder.featuredImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class BrokerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public TextView usersPerMonth;
        public ImageView featuredImage;

        public BrokerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            usersPerMonth = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_users_per_month);
            featuredImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_featured_image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mItemClickListener.onBrokerClick(mItems.get(position));
        }
    }

    interface BrokerItemClick {
        void onBrokerClick(Broker clickedBroker);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance again!

Comment: `brokerViewHolder.usersPerMonth.setText(currentItem.getUsersPerMonth());` - This line in the `onBindViewHolder()` method is calling `setText()` with an `int` argument. That overload expects the `int` to be a Resource identifier, but that Resource won't exist, which is why you get that Exception. Change that `int` to a `String`, and call `setText()` with that `String` instead. There are examples in the duplicate linked at the top of the page.

Comment: This totally worked for me, thank you a lot! @MikeM.